# Click Notification - Send to application

Tags: android

With my notification system, when the notification is sent, I would like to be able to click on the notification and have it send me to my application.  But, with my current code, it doesn't do so.  How can I fix that?

```
public void causeNotification(CharSequence contentText, CharSequence tickerText) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Sending notification - \"" + contentText + "\"");
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
    int icon = R.drawable.neoseeker_swoosh;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence contentTitle = "Neoseeker";
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Neoseeker.this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

    mNotificationManager.notify(Neoseeker.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step #1: Never call `getApplicationContext()`. `Neoseeker.this` apparently is a `Context` -- use it.

Step #2: `notificationIntent` is an empty `Intent`. That is not going to open any activities. You need to create an `Intent` that would start an activity, much like any `Intent` you would use with `startActivity()`.

Here is a [sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Notifications/Notify1/) from one of my books, showing the use of notifications.