# make notification when clicking app bring to front

Tags: android

I want make a notification, that when clicked on it will bring my app from the background to the front. I am using the following code:

```
NotificationManager noma = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pen = PendingIntent.getActivity(Timer.this, 0, intent, 0);
intent.putExtra("key", "trigerred");
String body = "This is a message";
String title = "This is title";
Notification no = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, body, System.currentTimeMillis());
no.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
no.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, body, pen);
noma.notify(uniqueID, no);
```

When I click on the notification that makes a new intent but I want the last created intent brought to the front. How i can do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Click Notification - Send to application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172966/click-notification-send-to-application)

Comment: post code where you get your intent object.

Comment: See the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575730/notification-to-restore-a-task-rather-than-a-specific-activity

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag on the intent that you pass to getActivity.
This should bring you back to the all ready running activity when clicking your notification.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestActivity_launchMode) for a list of the different launch flags.

Comment: i do this but it dows not effect. may give me an example please?

Comment: sorry, rereading the docs I think you need to set the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. This flag will launch the Activity into a new task, but if a task with this Activity all ready exists then it will bring it to the foreground instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
PendingIntent pen = PendingIntent.getActivity(Timer.this, 0, intent,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);
```